# The use of "about" vs "if/whether"

Tags: difference

Does the following sentences have the same meaning?

> I don't know if/whether she will come to our meeting.

> I don't know about her coming to our meeting.

Comment: They basically mean the same things: that it is unknown if she will show up at the meeting

Answer (score 1):

> 1: *I don't know if/whether she will come to our meeting.* (***if*** and ***whether*** are interchangeable here)
>    2: *I don't know about her coming to our meeting.*

The first one always and only means she may come to the meeting, but the speaker doesn't know whether she actually *will* come or not.

But the second one wouldn't normally mean that. Depending on context, it might mean the speaker didn't even realize her presence or absence is an issue of uncertainty (and by implication, that since he's heard nothing *about* the question, he obviously doesn't have an opinion on the matter). For this sense, the speaker might well say *I don't know **anything** about her coming to our meeting.*

But in many contexts, #2 would mean the speaker has ***misgivings*** about whether it would be a good idea for her to attend (because she's known to be awkward and disruptive in meetings, for example). The speaker may or may not be in a position to *control* whether she's "allowed" to attend - the implication is he's not convinced she should be (context dictates whether he's open to being persuaded that she *should* be present, that this isn't necessarily a *bad* thing, etc.).